# Is there a way to pass data between nested WordPress shortcodes within a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-plugin-creation

I know there is a way to do this, however, I am having a hard time understanding it. Here is my problem.

I have a shortcode that triggers a function that brings in a store inventory. I format the data that gets returned with HTML. My plugin does this already using the following shortcode `['inventory']`

What I would like to do is within the same function if possible I'd like to create a few more shortcodes such as `[product_id]`

And hopefully, from the same function place the current records product_id as that shortcode value as I loop through the records.

And also use some of the WordPress theme elements in combination with the shortcode.

So let's say the inventory shortcode returns the following

```
<div>
    <h1>Product ID {$product_id}</h1>
    <p>Price $price</p>
</div>
```

and loops through every product, so if there are 4 products it would output the above HTML 4 times.

The theme I am using allows me to create buttons specific to my theme, I don't want to hard code those buttons into my code.

What I want to do is the following

```
[inventory]
    ['record']
        //Insert theme buttons using themes builder
        <button value=['product_id']>Get more info</button>
    ['/record]
[/inventory]
```

So what I would like to do is have the inventory, generate the data to be outputted, but instead of looping through and outputting id like to loop through and pass the data to the ['record'] shortcode and then have that tag render the output with the buttons below each record. And give the button value the product_id shortcode which would hold the current records product ID.

I want to say do_shortcode is involved, but I am not quite sure how to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated

I have tried reading the documentation.

```
function inventory($atts, $content = null){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'storeid' => 'default',
    ), $atts));
//query that returns the store inventory
$query;

//Output formatted results FYI there is a whole function that but it pretty much just loops through the $query results.
    foreach($query as $queryResult){
        echo $queryResult;
    }
}
add_shortcode('inventory', 'inventory');


<div>
    <h1>Product ID {$product_id}</h1>
    <p>Price $price</p>
</div>
<button value="apple">Get More Info</button>
```

More Info

So I have a project I am working on but am having a hard time wrapping my mind around how to work with nested shortcodes.

Here is what I have

```
[inventory store=some_store_id category=fruit]
```

This shortcode currently returns the following from the database `[[0]="product_id"=>['name'=>'apple', 'price'=>'2.00'],[1]="another_product_id"=>['name'=>'apple', 'price'=>'2.00']]`

Id like to have something like this

```
<div>
[inventory store=some_store_id category=fruit]
[individual_product]
<div>
<h1>[product_id]</h1>
</div>
<div><h2>[name]</h2></div>
<div><p>[price]</p></div>
[/individual_product]
[/inventory]
</div>
```

Comment: `$content` of your inventory function contains everything between the [inventory] shortcode tags. You can do some find and replace code to put the product id in there, remove the [record] tags which are really like template tags here and not a shortcode, and then call `do_shortcode` on the modified string to handle any shortcodes the themes builder has added. I'm testing and typing up an answer.

Comment: If you actually want to use another shortcode for record and pass the id in, you can call do_shortcode on a shortcode string like `do_shortcode( [record product_id=4 ] );`

Comment: So when you pass in the record shortcode in the record and set the product_id to 4 does that then give the record shortcode access to the product_id value? Or are you saying create the record shortcode and give it a product_id attribute and then set the attribute in the do_shortcode?

Comment: Set the content's attribute value inside of the first shortcode with a str_replace, and then call do_shortcode on that string. Formatting an answer with code now...

Comment: How about using add_filter() for this purpose? The Shortcode API doc https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API gives advice on nested shortcodes and mentions add_filter as a way to do it.

Comment: Sure, I think readability and maintainability are what you want to focus on here so if you'll never use the inner shortcode as a standalone function, you could try using a filter.

Comment: How does that filter look? Im going to add to my original post shortly. With more detail.

Answer (score 0):

`$content` of your inventory function contains everything between the [inventory] shortcode tags. You can do some find and replace code to put the product id in there as an attribute, and then call do_shortcode on the modified string to handle any shortcodes the themes builder has added. I found that the brackets around product_id were problematic unless you're calling another shortcode there...

```
function inventory_shortcode_function( $atts, $content = null ){

  // do inventory query here
  $inventory = [1,2,3];

  $output = '<p>There are ' . count( $inventory ) . ' items.</p>';

  foreach( $inventory as $item ) {
    $loop_content = str_replace( '[record]', '[record product_id="' . $item . '"]', $content );
    $output .= '<div>' . do_shortcode( $loop_content ) . '</div>';
  }

  return $output;
}
add_shortcode('inventory', 'inventory_shortcode_function' );


function record_shortcode_function( $atts, $content = null ){
  extract( shortcode_atts([ 'product_id' => -1], $atts ) );

  return do_shortcode( str_replace( 'product_id', $product_id, $content ) );
}
add_shortcode('record', 'record_shortcode_function' );
```

This is the content I placed in the content editor:

```
[inventory]
  [record]
  //Insert theme buttons using themes builder
  <button value="product_id">Get more info</button>
  [/record]
[/inventory]
```

And this is the generated html:

```
<p>There are 3 items.</p>
<div>
  //Insert theme buttons using themes builder
  <button value="1">Get more info</button></div>
<div>
  //Insert theme buttons using themes builder
  <button value="2">Get more info</button>
</div>
<div>
  //Insert theme buttons using themes builder
  <button value="3">Get more info</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by $content of your inventory function contains everything between the [inventory] shortcode tags. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Sure, in this example, `inventory_shortcode_function( $atts, $content = null ){` is the signature of the inventory shortcode function. `$content = null` means there is a parameter called $content which defaults to null, but the way the shortcode system works in WordPress, this variable $content contains all of the content that was between the opening and closing `[inventory]` tags in the editor.